# copying files using a batch file....windows

Tags: batch-file

I have a file copyfiles.bat and i want to do the following inside of my batch file:

```
 copy "C:\temp\file1.txt" "c:\users\me\my directory"
 copy "C:\temp\dir2\file2.txt" "c:\users\me\my directory\dir2"
```

I save and run the batch file and nothing is being copied. All files and directories exist. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: What is the output of your batch file? Did you get an error message or `1 file(s) copied`

Comment: it says the files were copied, but the date/time clearly shows nothing happened

Comment: `but the date/time clearly shows nothing happened` - Why? What do you expect for the times? Did you inspect the files? Are they are equal? Please add the informations to your question, you already has

Comment: date times are how i know the files changed. I made an edit to a file 10 minutes ago and the destination directory's files in 30 minutes old, the time should change. I'll keep reading on this.

Comment: If the target file exists there must appear a prompt `Overwrite file1.txt? (Yes/No/All):`; do you get such? does `my directory` already exist?

Comment: yes, i get the prompt.

Comment: So I assume you are answering it with `Y` (you could also do `copy /Y` to do that automatically). What timestamp are you talking about: last modification date or creation date?

Answer (score 0):

Try xcopy command instead of copy.
[Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/240268) is official docs about it

Answer (score 0):

Give file name for destination path also like below

copy "C:\temp\file1.txt" "c:\users\me\my       directory\file1.txt"

Sometimes directory names with space in between will also cause issue.I faced such an issue once. Please check with directory names without space in between.

To replace the existing file /Y option is also required, which will suppress the prompt  for asking whether you want to replace.

Comment: I removed the quotes from around the destination path..Added the /y and now it works. Thanks